# Can't seem to get my radio inline with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For the life of me I can't seem to get inline rather than stacked radio options.

Here's the code - just a simple, name, age, gender etc. form.

Running example here: https://jsfiddle.net/a0cbo5rz/2/

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100vh">    
    <div class="col-4">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" autocomplete="off" method="post">
                    <label for="nickname">Nickname: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="nickname" class="form-control" name="nickname" placeholder="Enter nickname" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="radio inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender", id="Male", checked="checked" value="M">
                            Male
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="radio inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender", id="Female", value="F">
                            Female
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <label for="age">Age: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="age" min="18" max="99" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="country">Country: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" name="country" placeholder="Select country" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="location">Location: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control" name="location" placeholder="Location" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="login-form-complete" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="form-inline"> it's because of this class look carefully...

Comment: Is it a requirement for each radio input element to be in its own div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, this might help you out.

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100vh">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" autocomplete="off" method="post">
                    <label for="nickname">Nickname: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="nickname" class="form-control" name="nickname" placeholder="Enter nickname" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
                        <label class="radio inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender", id="Male", checked="checked" value="M">
                            Male
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender", id="Female", value="F">
                            Female
                        </label><br>
                    <label for="age">Age: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="age" min="18" max="99" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="country">Country: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" name="country" placeholder="Select country" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="location">Location: </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control" name="location" placeholder="Location" required>
                    </div>
                    <!--                            <button type="button" id="sendlogin" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                     -->
                    <input type="submit" name="login-form-complete" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! (I had to study that for a few minutes to find the difference :D )